# WTForms custom validator crashes instead of returning error message

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to make what should be a really simple validator using WTForms - ensuring that input is a) present and b) a number of some type (float or int are both OK). I wrote the following class and added it to the validators.py library in WTForms:

```
class MyValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        if not field.data:
            if self.message is None:
                message = field.gettext('This field is required.')
                return ValidationError(self.message)

        try:
            val = float(field.data)
        except NameError:
            self.message = ('Input must be a number')
            raise ValidationError(self.message)
        return field.data
```

And added it to my form:

```
class foo(Form):
    bar = IntegerField('foo',[validators.MyValidator()])
```

This causes my Flask app to crash when I get to validation stage (`if not foo.validate`, where foo is an instance of the foo class), with this traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\~~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\wtforms\validators.py", line 158, in __call__
    val = float(field.data)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

This is pretty annoying. How do I just return False? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found my mistake. It was embarrassingly simple, and my instinct was to delete the question, but maybe the code will be helpful for someone else in the future.

The exception line should of course read:

```
except (TypeError, NameError):
```